# Blazor and Active Directory -Is getting it working here different than net core 5 MVC? And is that different that getting it working with Azure AD?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I have past net core 5 MVC applcation that  I am rewriting in Blazor server.

The code I have used in MVC to get it working includes the following:

```
        public void GetADinfo(out string givenName, out string surname, out string homePhone, out string email)
    {
        //===========================================================
        //Go and get AD info for the current user or equivalent
        var components = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
        var username = components.Last();
        // create LDAP connection object
        DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);

        search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        DirectoryEntry dsresult = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        givenName = dsresult.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
        surname = dsresult.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
        email = dsresult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
        homePhone = dsresult.Properties["homePhone"][0].ToString();

        //=============================================================================
    }




    public DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
    {
        // create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings

        string ADconn = _context.ApplicConfs.Select(s => s.Ldapconn).FirstOrDefault();
        string LDAPConn = _context.ApplicConfs.Select(s => s.Ldappath).FirstOrDefault();

        //string ADconn;
        //ADconn = "SERVER.A3HR.local";
        //string LDAPConn;
        //LDAPConn = "LDAP://SERVER.A3HR.local";
        //DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("SERVER.A3HR.local");

        //ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://OU=staffusers,DC=leeds-art,DC=ac,DC=uk";
        //ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://SERVER.A3HR.local";

        DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(ADconn);

        ldapConnection.Path = LDAPConn;

        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        return ldapConnection;
    }
```

Does the code for using Active Directory in Blazor Server require anything different? In other words is the authentication different using Blazor as compared to net core MVC?

My app uses Blazor server windows authentication. So I get current user in the normal Blazor way. When I get that I want to use the current userid to look up the email and telephone number in AD and pre-populate it on a page if it exists. That way - in the application- the user doesn't have to re enter this information all the time.

Does anyone have an example of this using Blazor? Is the approach dramatically different between local AD and Azure AD in the logic/coding used? I see a few examples of Azure AD use in Blazor out there.

Thanks for any information provided...

Comment: I can't answer that, but I can give one hint.  The Blazor default scaffolded membership system is not Blazor at all-- it uses mvc.  I found this quite annoying, as I went straight from Web Forms to Blazor, and did not want to have to learn about MVC.  My point is that I think you will be able to re-use almost 100% of what you've already done in your existing project.

Comment: i will try to pursue the above then and see how far i get